# Make Excel use more Memory

Tags: excel, memory, configuration

My workstation has 64 bit windows 7, 8 cores 3.5gHz CPU, 32G memory and SSD.

The excel version is Office 365 MSO(16.0.11001.20070) 64-bit

But recently I packed a bunch of data to an Excel file only take 1,380 KB hard drive.
Once I open it, the Excel gets very lag. And I see it is trying to use under 2G memory all the time.

The excel contains about 150,000 decimal number and 4 plots on about 20,000 numbers.

Is there any way to make it use more memory?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel handles the memory usage itself. You can't make it use more as it already uses the memory it "needs".

You could try to set the task priority to high in the task manager.

1. List item
2. Task manager
3. Details
4. search for the process `EXCEL.EXE`
5. right click it --> select priority --> high

I hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, that helps a little. I guess that's the only way